# Python - replacing string/symbol with numbers

Tags: python, data-conversion

I have some columns in a pandas dataframe consisting of strings, which I want to convert to numbers (float). The problem is the following: some entries consist of just `'-'` and others are like `'1E-06'`. Is there an easy way to replace just the `'-'` symbol, e.g. with a number -- using for example `df['col'].str.replace('-','1000')`, without modifying the string `'1E-06'`? Otherwise, `'1E-06'` will be also modified, e.g. into `'1E100006'`, which will then affect the subsequent conversion into float numbers.

Comment: `df['col'].str.replace('^-$','1000')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':['-','1e-06']})
df['value'] = df['value'].replace('-', '1000')
```

OR:

```
df['value'].replace('-', '1000', inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
value
100
1e-06
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
for string in your_stuff:
    string = string.replace('-','1000') if string == '-' else string;
```

alternatively use

```
map(lambda string: string.replace('-','1000') if string == '-' else string, your_stuff)
```